# UnityEvent but with only one Listener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I was making an asset which is just some usual stuff i do with all my games so i dont have to do it everytime. in one of my script i have an enum which contains values like Custom1,Custom2,...

and the main script which holds some color properties. based on the enum selected i want to invoke a specific method from any user generated script so for that reason i require an array of event.

i added a UnityEvent variable so i can reference functions from other script but then i found out that i cant invoke a single method from that list of methods in UnityEvent.

my work around that problem is have an Array of UnityEvent so i can invoke a specific indexed Event but this is not a good way to do it because each individual Element is also a list of event where i want it to have only 1 reference to method.

so how can i make sure that you cant add more than one method reference and remove the unnecessary + and - Button from each element of Array of UnityEvents.

or

how can i invoke a specific Method from a UnityEvent.

my array of UnityEvent in `ColorManager` Script.
`public UnityEvent<ColorFollower>[] CustomFunctions;`

my enum in `ColorFollower` Script

```
public enum CustomComponentType {
    Custom1,
    Custom2,
    Custom3,
    Custom4,
    Custom5,
    Custom6,
    Custom7,
    Custom8,
    Custom9,
    Custom10
}

    public CustomComponentType customComponentType = CustomComponentType.Custom1;
```

thats how i currently invoke

```
if (colorManager.CustomFunctions.Length > (int) customComponentType) {
    UnityEvent<ColorFollower> customFunction = colorManager.CustomFunctions[(int) customComponentType];
    customFunction?.Invoke((ColorFollower) this);
}
```

Comment: That's not how events work .. you can always have 0 to n listeners. If you want one that is limited to 0 or 1 listener you will have to implement your own type with special drawer .. but it is far beyond trivial .. see [`UnityEvent` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent/UnityEvent.cs) and [`UnityEventPropertyDrawer` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs/)

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Why do you want to remove the + and - ? And yes, derHugo is right. This applies to any type of "triggered" code, be it Unity events or C# listeners. You might be confusing events with callbacks. Your `CustomX` design is also not very friendly. If you want to implement something, implement it, don't make some custom var that might or might not be used in the future. You can also consider ScriptableObjects "enumerators" here (although I am not a fan). Polymorphism is your friend and I think the best solution here.

Comment: Is what you want ment to be configured via the Inspector? Otherwise you could just have a `Dictionary<CustomComponentType, Action<ColorFollower>>` .. `Action<T>` still doesn't ensure there is a single listener but usually suggests it. So you could simply check if a listener has already been registered for a certain enum key and if so reject the other ..

Comment: It is ment to be assign by the user of the asset thats why i said from inspector originally i assumed if i publish my asset the user would programmatically add a listener to delegates for changes in values but that sounds to advance for some users and the usability also reduces thats why i thought if user can add their function to inspector that would be more clear and readable but it only requires one function to run what user wants and if a user accidentally assigns some wrong method than the functionality would break and vause errors thats why i decided user should only add 1 method.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`UnityEvent<ColorFollower> customFunction = colorManager.CustomFunctions[(int) customComponentType];`

Whenever is executed, `customFunction` variable gets overridden and assigned only the corresponding `colorManager.CustomFunctions[(int) customComponentType]` function. That's why you always can invoke only one method. Instead, you want to subscribe the new method, i.e.

`UnityEvent<ColorFollower> customFunction += colorManager.CustomFunctions[(int) customComponentType];`

`+=` makes all the difference and allows you to subscribe to multiple methods from that single `UnityEvent` variable.

Comment: no that is actually not the issue it is a totally different line in the ColorFollower script so nothing is overridden and the issue is not with functionality. the work around i had is not an optimum way of doing what i described in question.